# MySQL query with DATE() function on LocalDateTime field

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a query like this:

```
@Query("SELECT rhwp.pk.reservation FROM ReservationHasWorkingPlace rhwp WHERE rhwp.pk.workingPlace.idWorkingPlace = ?1 AND NOT (DATE(rhwp.pk.reservation.endDateTime) < ?2 OR DATE(rhwp.pk.reservation.startDateTime) > ?3)")
List<Reservation> getReservationsForWPAndDateInterval(Integer idWorkingPlace, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
```

where I compare a DateTime stored into database with the localDate passed through the java method.
I receive this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2018-04-20] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

There is a way to configure hibernate/jpa to make this conversion automatically or I have to pass a Date object instead LocalDate?
I have tried importing even hibernate-java8 but no changed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

converting with Using java.sql.Date.valueOf(start) works

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use @Converter. Example with converting LocalDateTime to Timestamp:

```
@Converter
public class SomeConverterName implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(final LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(final Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

And then on the entity field use:

```
@Column(name = "somefield")
@Convert(converter = SomeConverterName.class)
private LocalDateTime someDate;
```

Comment: on database I don't need the coverter to store the data, the mapping to LocalDateTime to DateTiem is automatically, the problem is the use of DATE() function

Comment: hmm right. I think because DATE is a db function it can only be used in native query. Try rewriting the query to native and add nativeQuery = true in @Query annotation to double check that.

Comment: I think that DATE return an object different from LocalDate and so throw exception. If the function was not usable with @Query an errore appeared during deploy

Comment: converting with Using java.sql.Date.valueOf(start) works